# Java API for "indexed" property files

Tags: java, api, properties

I am looking for a Java API which allows to write and read the property files in the following format:

```
<prefix>.<index>.<suffix>=<value>
```

For example:

```
launcher.1.id=23
launcher.1.name=abc
launcher.1.date=123123
launcher.2.id=sdfsdf
launcher.2.name=Asdfdsf
launcher.2.date=ghfgh
cec.1.id=sdfsdf
cec.1.name=Asdfdsf
cec.1.date=ghfgh
cec.2.id=sdfsdf
cec.2.name=Asdfdsf
cec.2.date=ghfgh
#...
```

log4j uses very similar format for configuring the appenders:

```
log4j.rootLogger=debug, stdout, R
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p 
log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File=example.log
log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=100KB
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%p %t %c - %m%n
```

Anybody has an idea if there is a Java library for a case like this?

Thanks,
Ilya

Comment: Any way you could turn this into an XML/JSON file? There's a lot of support for serializing / deserializing these standard format types

Comment: +1 on @ControlAltDel's idea. Doing this in property files is confusing, just use JSON.

Comment: @ControlAltDel thanks for the idea, I think we will reconsider our property files format in favor of JSON :) Can you reply with an "answer", I will then accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct solution was to reconsider the format and use JSON for this. Thank you @ControlAltDel for the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into [Apache commons-configuration](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/)? They provide xpath-like support to query such property files, and will further let you migrate back and forth between xml, ini and the like, should you ever decide to change the format.

Comment: I have seen the commons-configuration but unfortunately it's not quite the API I am looking for.

Answer (score -1):

There are two possibilities:

1. You add a property that defines how many numbered items exist - e.g. `launcher.count = 2`
2. You enumerate all keys and look for the suitable pattern:

   ```
   for (Object o : properties.keySet()) {
       String key = (String) o;
       if (key.startsWith("launcher")) {
           ...
       } else if (key.startsWith("cec")) {
           ...
       } 
   }
   ```

Comment: This is exactly why I am looking for a consistent API: not to write this code by myself

Answer (score -2):

```
java.util.Properties

String string = properties.getProperty("launcher.1.name");
properties.setProperty("launcher.1.name", "abc");
```

If you need all Properties in an enumeration,

```
public Enumeration<?> propertyNames()

Returns an enumeration of all the keys in this property list, 
including distinct keys in the default property list if a key of 
the same name has not already been found from the main properties list.
```

Comment: -1 This isn't what the OP is looking for, they want to fetch properties with a certain pattern

Comment: @millimoose, check this docuemntation. The so called "key" can be any format including 3 dots or 5 million dots.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#getProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29
I have upvoted you in protest..

Comment: @millimoose
As an example, each of the following three lines specifies the key "Truth" and the associated element value "Beauty":

 Truth = Beauty
        Truth:Beauty
 Truth                  :Beauty

Comment: What the OP wants is something like `properties.getAllProperties("launcher.*.name");`, that returns a list or map of all values for properties with names like `launcher.1.name`, or `launcher.puppies.name`. That is, to **not** have to specify all the property keys.

Comment: @millimoose, Where exactly OP said that!! All they said was to read and write a property.

Comment: @millimoose, Where exactly OP said that!! All they said was to read and write a property. Even if so, propertyNames() gives them all in an enumeration.

Comment: Did you read the title:  Java API for “indexed” property files?  It implies he wants an API which saves him the pain of code for this manually (typically by iterating over all the keys).  It doesn't imply he needs help with the Properties class itself.

Comment: @srini.venigalla The OP says that anytime he says "indexed". It's also heavily implied by the examples provided, where there are lots of property keys that follow a pattern. Your answer still just says what to use when implementing the code the OP doesn't want to implement. (Which is why he's asking for a library.)